# Trouble locating the lateral sewer line to house

Tags: sewer, locating

I am having trouble locating the lateral sewer line to my house. So far I have tried all of the following:

Have looked for 'S' marking on the sidewalk concrete - not legible/wiped out, no cleanouts near the front of the property..

Had had two plumbers try to locate with camera-snake & magnet device, both of them had marked close-bu spots and depth, but the sewer line is not to be found after digging (about 7.5 feet) .

Have contacted the sanitary district, but they don't have exact maps of lateral line to the property, only partial arch proposals from way back when (1960s)

Has anyone faced such a problem? Are there other methods to fish out the lateral line to property?

Comment: A bit of an XY problem here. **Why** do you need to find the sewer line? Big clog that snaking can't get through? Can't be that because camera-snake & magnet wouldn't get through either. Suspect broken pipe? Usually you'd see damage resulting from that.

Comment: we are doing an extension with bathroom, the extension’s bathroom needs to connect to the main line.

Comment: another way could be to use a thin metal rod to probe the ground until you hit something that sounds like a pipe, it needs to be thin enough to push in by hand  - not going to work well if the ground is stony or full of wood.

Comment: did you dig close to sidewalk or close to house.  the house exit should be the highest exit point.  I'd just trench at the house where the sewer line is exiting...  shouldn't be much deeper than your footing.  you can also typically tell the difference between disturbed and undisturbed soil depending on your geology.

Comment: Yes, we dug at two of the points points that the plumbers identified- dug about 7 feet of dirt, but it will be hard (labor/cost) to dig a trench along the whole of the foundation. I am hoping to get a more precise location of the sewer lateral before I dig again.  Is there a more precise tool or mechanism that can detect sewer line from above ground?

Comment: I affixed a battery powered audio beep generator to the end of a sewer snake and assembled a geophone from junk parts -- basically a sensitive microphone acoustically coupled to a spike that I could press to the ground. A high gain amplifier fed earmuff-type headphones. I advanced the sewer snake to a distance that should have put the beeper in an accessible spot and then probed the ground every 2 feet perpendicular till I could hear a beep. And hot dang, it worked! The line was about 6 feet down. Such equipment is commercially available.

Comment: Call your local utility locating agency (the agency any contractor is supposed to contact before excavating in public right of way) and have them mark your street in front of your house?  They'll probably only mark up to your property line, but it's a start.

Comment: In our tract neighborhood of ~270 houses most have sanitary sewer lines that go through the front yard to the main under the street, but a few houses in one area are over a hill and drain to a different main. In these the sewer goes through the back yard and under the back alley. Do you or your neighbors know where your city sewer line is? You may get a clue by looking at the roof vents. Sometimes a vent is on the main line under your house. If the cleanout is cast iron, you may be able to detect it with a metal detector. The sewer line itself may be too far down for a metal detector.